# CSS Sticky footer where main content is set position:absolute?

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have a site where the main content is set to `position:absolute`.

I have set up my footer to be at the bottom of the page as so:

```
position:absolute;
bottom: 0;
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
```

This works fine if the content does not exceed the height of the page. But when it does the footer stays in place whilst the content scrolls underneath it.

I have tried [Ryan Faits sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) but this doesnt seem to work when the main content has position:absolute set.

Would anyone know a good way of doing this? Ultimately I just want the footer to always be at the bottom of the page - doesnt have to follow the user up as they scroll.

My site is here if you want to take a look: http://www.theoutlookcafedubbo.com.au/newsite/index.php?id=2

Comment: You could try using `position:fixed` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your CSS to this if you want your footer to always be on the bottom of the screen:

```
#footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #000000;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: url(tmpimages/darkwall.png);
}
```

If you are looking for a true "Sticky Footer", try the following:

Firstly Twitter Bootstrap has a nice means of doing this. [Link is here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/)

Or you could use the CSS Sticky Footer [See here](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)

The key is to create a negative bottom margin in the main container, using the exact height you want your footer to be.

I hope this helps.